# HighCharts Vue JS - CSV key

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm using csv-loader from webpack to load my CSV file and it loads fine on my Vue JS app.

The data.csv key is populated but the chart is not displayed.
App is being served locally.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'
import csvPath from './assets/test.csv'
import Papa from 'papaparse'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    highcharts: Chart
  },

  data () {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },
        data: {
          csv: csvPath
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Units'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

CSV File

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
```

I expect to see a fully plotted graph (barchart).

Comment: Any error in the console ? Do the tittle "Fruit Consumption" appear ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import and initialize the `data` Highcharts module like that:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import dataModule from "highcharts/modules/data";

dataModule(Highcharts);
```